# Same film different pantone colour

Tags: print-design, gradient, pantone, prepress

I am doing press project that needs to be mass produced soon. The Metallic Green 7870C is only available at this print shop. I have gradient artwork and using tint, working in AI CS6. If I use different Pantone colour as 'template' to make the black film, will it work? Will the tint and gradient affect much if different colour?

Edited:
I make this packaging design with 2 colours: Black and Pantone Metallic Green 7870C. The print shop, who will mass produce this, have the metallic colour, but I don't. They need the colour separation file to make the film.

Because I don't have the Pantone code (Metallic Green), I used Metalic Silver colour as a guide and proceed to colour separation.

The template result looks similar to what we want, but I want to make sure, if we use that film as a template for other Pantone colour, will it affect to the artwork's gradient?

Thanks!

Comment: Hum. I do not get the idea. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: I make this packaging design with 2 colours: Black and Pantone Metallic Green 7870C. The print shop, who will mass produce this, have the metallic colour, but I don't. They need the colour separation file to make the film. Because I don't have the Pantone code (Metallic Green), I used Metalic Silver colour as a guide and proceed to colour separation. The template result looks similar to what we want, but I want to make sure, if we use that film as a template for other Pantone colour, will it affect to the artwork's gradient?

Comment: Gradient with metallic pantone... that's risky. Ask your printer to be sure it's alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you mean that you do not have that color inside your pallete on the program you are using, right? Let us say your pantone pallete is not updated. Is that correct?

I think you can download the latests palletes from the pantone.com site. But it has being a long time since I did that the last time.

But you can send the file in any pantone you like, for example chocolate mousse and in the print house they simply put another ink when printing. Just stay in comunication with them making that clear... so they do not fill their machine with chocolate mousse.

Answer (score 1):

If you're providing a file from which to write a film for burning the plate, submit it in black with a note attached saying the ink is to be Pantone Metallic Green 7870C.  Probably add that text in BOLD outside the cut lines, too, just so it doesn't get lost.